# How do I do Debugging and Error Handling in my Xamarin Android application which has reference to .Net Standard Library project

Tags: c#, android, debugging, xamarin, error-handling

I am referencing the .Net Standard Library project in a Xamarin project. When there is an error, I don't know how to debug it, even though I have added exception handling in Android, it does not call that.

If I am running it in debug mode there is just a message in the IDE that an exception occurred without giving any details as to what happened.

And, if I am running it in Ctrl+F5 Non-Debugging then the Application just crashes in the Emulator.

So how do I go about debugging in Xamarin?

There are 2 things:

1. Debug and Check the Error which occurred in the .Net Standard Project
2. Debug and Check the Error which occurred in the Android Project

Comment: Can you show any of the code that causes the crash? Exception handling and debugging are different. In Android, you can see the log on the device, I'm assuming you are setting breakpoints too. Try setting one at the start of either App.xaml.cs if using forms or in your launch activity if using Xamarin native

Comment: I have some error handling code in android for logging the error to a txt file in the special folder MyDocuments. But where should this file get created in windows when we do ctrl+f5. Is it in the c:\users\<user>\documents folder

Comment: no, it will write to the device's file system.  Your Android app doesn't have access to your PC's file system.

Comment: @smith putting breakpoints helped a little bit. I have raised a separate question for the code which causes the crash. please see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113327/why-does-connection-object-contain-null-properties-in-it