# Why does Connection Object contain Null properties in it

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying this code and in debugging breakpoint the Connection Object does not show any values in it when I hover on it. All values are shown NULL. Even the connection string is null.

This is the code;

```
<Button HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Click To Connect" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"></Button>

        private async void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string SqlServer_ServerPath_Server = "192.199.199.199";
            string SqlServer_Database_Server = "someDatabase";
            string SqlServer_User_Server = "someUser";
            string SqlServer_Password_Server = "somePassword";
            int timeOutInSeconds = 15;

            string connectionString = "Server=" + SqlServer_ServerPath_Server + ";" + "Database=" + SqlServer_Database_Server + ";" + "User=" + SqlServer_User_Server + ";" + "Password=" + SqlServer_Password_Server + ";" + "Trusted_Connection=false" + ";" + "Connection Timeout=" + timeOutInSeconds + ";" + "Persist Security Info=False";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                con.Open();

                // !!! THIS LINE THROWS Exception because con object contains all null values in it (including the 'State' and 'Connection String')
                await DisplayAlert("Success", con.State.ToString(), "OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Could Not Connect [" + ex.Message + "]", "Error", "OK");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please note, I am using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient; in my Xamarin Project. Is it because of that that the Connection feels the Connection String is no ok

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the connection string is not following the correct format.

**Try this format:**

`Data Source=192.199.199.199; initial catalog=someDatabase;user id= someUser;password=somePassword;`

Comment: If I use my connection string in a Winforms application, it works fine. Then why it does not work in Xamarin.

Comment: Please note, I am using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient; in my Xamarin Project. Is it because of that that the Connection feels the Connection String is no ok

Comment: I don't think you can directly connect to a SQL server via Xamarin app. You have to either use a local database like 'SQLite.NET' or use a REST API that connects to your SQL database.

Comment: SQLite - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases / REST API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest